# Concerns about MathJax in proposed new SE editor

Tags: discussion, mathjax, user-interface, stackexchange, editor

Over on [Physics.SE](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13349/the-proposed-changes-to-the-text-editor-would-break-this-site), Emilio Pisanty has pointed out that the proposed new StackExchange editor (currently in alpha testing) would present major difficulties for MathJax-heavy Stacks such as this one.  In particular, the design philosophy seems to be leading towards removing the simultaneous preview and towards a more WYSIWYG interface.  This makes a lot of sense for posts that are mostly textual;  in fact, it would make it easier for newer users who are not familiar with Markdown or who are copy-and-pasting from a rich text format.  However, it would also make writing and revising math-heavy posts much, much more cumbersome.

Emilio has written up these concerns as an [answer to the announcement of the alpha test.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/360142/373793) As this change would also affect this site, I would encourage the denizens of Math.SE to take a look at his answer and provide polite and constructive feedback to the dev team via that forum.

Comment: I read the thread on meta.se and meta.mo and the only hope I see is something similar to [prosemirror-math](https://github.com/benrbray/prosemirror-math). However I still believe that the current editor is better when you have to write large amount of math (say an integral evaluation with 20 steps and no text in between). The value of current editor is seen when one makes a latex error and tries to rectify it.

Comment: As I have posted on the main thread, this will have a big effect on new users unfamiliar with mathematical typesetting (and we have many of them). They need to be encouraged rather than put off - the site is for mathematics at any level including beginners.