# Can one use Stack Exchange to render mathematical equations for personal use?

Tags: discussion, support, mathjax

Is it ok to use the "body" part (of questions and answers) to render LaTeX equations for personal use?

In other words is it OK to use it as a LaTeX editor-compiler for non Stack related purposes?

Comment: There are also freely-available, full-featured versions of TeX that are self-installing on MacOS, for example. TeXShop is what I've been using for years.

Comment: I don't know what uses you are having but I generally use [Stackedit](https://stackedit.io/app#) because it's easier to handle and see all that is going on.

Comment: I don't see why not, but [this resource](https://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php) is probably more useful to you as you can adjust the size of the output.

Comment: Thank you all for the responses. I found compiling here extremely user friendly and easy to use(from uploading images, to chemical equations). Cheers!

Comment: It would be nice if there was some standalone code somewhere equivalent to the edit / live preview function.  The closest I've found is http://bandicoot.maths.adelaide.edu.au/MathJax/test/sample-dynamic-2.html but it's rather primitive.  I've been using it in teaching classes to render math on the fly, but wish I had something better.

Comment: @NateEldredge SageMathCell can render MathJax. (In fact, it can render HTML, with embedded MathJax). [Here](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxzyMwrSS1KTC7hSklNU0jTSEksSbT1zCsoLXHKr9Aoz0wpybA1MdBRyEjNTM8osbXQ1LTiUgCC4oz8co2MktwcsA5NTQB-4Bd9&lang=sage) is a basic example. Enter some MathJax (with dollar delimiters) into the data box, then click outside the data box.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

As long as you don't *submit* the post, I don't see *any* harm in using the preview functionality of Stack Exchange to test your LaTeX code. But see [Concerns about MathJax in proposed new SE editor](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33094/228959) – at the moment it's unclear whether that will continue to work. Otherwise, we have the [Formatting Sandbox](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/370/228959) which can be used for this kind of stuff.

Note that the language we use here is *MathJax*, not the real LaTeX. I don't have enough experience to list the most important differences, but you might want to use an (online) LaTeX compiler instead. [This question](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3354/117218) on TeX Meta lists two of them.

Comment: Sometimes things don't render correctly in Preview for me, but work okay when posted. Having used the answer box to write up a bit of LaTeX, as the OP wonders about, I once hit "Submit" to "really" see how some LaTeX rendered. My "answer" quickly picked up a downvote before I remembered where I was and got a chance to delete it. I was very embarrassed. Learn from my mistake.

Comment: It seems that the formula editor of Mathjax [is the same](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/378732/what-is-the-difference-between-latex-and-mathjax) as in LaTeX

Comment: @Jonas Eh... technically LaTeX doesn't have a formula editor. It would be more precise to say that the markup language used in LaTeX to express formulas is the same as the markup language used in MathJax to express formulas. (Though I don't even think it's 100% the same. The basics are the same, yes, but there are more advanced things that differ.)

Answer (score 3):

For personal use, you could use a template HTML file that accesses MathJax directly.  The example template below uses the MathJax website.  It also has a commented out portion in the header that you could use if you download MathJax to your computer.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
                    MathJax.Hub.Config({"HTML-CSS": { preferredFont: "TeX", availableFonts: ["STIX","TeX"], linebreaks: { automatic:true }, EqnChunk: (MathJax.Hub.Browser.isMobile ? 10 : 50) },
                                        tex2jax: { inlineMath: [ ["$", "$"], ["\\\\(","\\\\)"] ], displayMath: [ ["$$","$$"], ["\\[", "\\]"] ], processEscapes: true, ignoreClass: "tex2jax_ignore|dno" },
                                        TeX: {  equationNumbers: {autoNumber: "all"}, noUndefined: { attributes: { mathcolor: "red", mathbackground: "#FFEEEE", mathsize: "90%" } }, 
                                        Macros: { href: "{}" } },
                                        messageStyle: "none"
                });
</script>        

<script type="text/javascript" 
  src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
</script>  
<!--
<script type="text/javascript" 
  src="/home/external_libs/MathJax-2.7.7/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
</script>  
-->
</head>

<body>

Type your text here.  Example equation:
$$
  \sin^2(x) + \cos^2(x) = 1.
$$
    
</body>
</html>
```

Then simply view the edited template HTML file in almost any web browser.

Comment: This works great!  Of course, it only works if I am on line.  And mathjax.org is on line.

Comment: @GEdgar The commented out portion lets you use this offline. I downloaded MathJax (from Github I think) to the directory "/home/external_libs/MathJax-2.7.7" on my computer.  If you download MathJax, change the directory name in the template to the location of MathJax on your computer, uncomment the commented out portion, and comment out the <script></script> block linking to the MathJax website, you can use this offline.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to compile an equation, LaTeX2PNG is an option. As you could probably guess, it converts LaTeX to an image format.

http://latex2png.com/